# What is the StarTeam equivalent to 'git log'

Tags: version-control, starteam

How can I view the equivalent information provided by the Git command 'git log' in StarTeam?

Comment: What does 'git log' do in Git?

Comment: @Slapout the command 'git log' shows the commit history starting with the most recent commit. It includes who committed, when the commit was made and the commit message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*The command 'git log' shows the commit history starting with the most recent commit.

It includes who committed, when the commit was made and the commit message.*"
-- *[Mike Rylander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444639/mike-rylander)*

In *StarTeam* you have the **History tab** -
just select the file (or other Item you wish to review) in the upper panel,
and its history will show at the lower panel.

There are also reports that allow you to export that information as HTML.

EDIT: **To see all the files that where part of a given check-in**:

- If all were checked-in in a single operation and assigned to a CR,
  then you can catch this via the links:
  Find the CR-revision linked to that file-revision,
  then find the other files that are linked to that CR-revision.
- If recent check-ins, you can look at the last check-ins by date.
- Developers can be instructed to keep track of their checkin operations
  by joining the relevant file-revisions to a single revision-label
  (will be hard to enforce this tedious flow).
- Later versions of StarTeam support **Change Packets** which should help
  manage changes as atomic operations on groups of files.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to show all the files that where part of a given check-in?

Comment: If all were checked-in in a single operation and assigned to a CR, then you can catch this via the links: find the CR-revision linked to that file-revision, then find the other files that are linked to that CR-revision. If recent check-ins, you can look at the last check-ins by date. Third way: file-revisions has to by joined to a single revision-label.